# Is there a way to get the list of open editors in vscode (or at least the editor that was open before switching to the current editor) like Ctrl+tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In emacs I use a command which switches immediately to the previous buffers in use.  Repeatedly using this toggles back and forth between the two buffers. In vscode, the Ctrl+tab function behaves like this if you press and release.  My issue is the annoying popup editor select window that briefly appears.  I wanted to write an extension that just goes to the previous editor in use.  There are commands that go to the "previous editor" but this means the previous editor in the list of the editors not the last one in use so it cycles through all editors.  I looked at the code which Ctrl+tab uses but the interface it uses does not seem to be exposed to extensions.  Ctrl+tab clearly knows what the previous editor in use is because it selects it as the default choice in the pop up list.  How can I do that without the popup?

Comment: keep track of the active editor URL, `ChangedTextEditor` event, keep a recently used stack, also monitor `CloseEditor` event, and on using your command, `vscode.open` the element below the top op stack

Comment: just to be clear, the `Go Back` command (command palette) is _not_ what you are looking for? Does usage of the Open Editors sub-view of the Explorer View help in any way? What about the `Go Previous in Edit Locations`, `Go Previous in Navigation Locations`, and `Go to Previous Change` commands?

Comment: @rioV8 Yeah, I thought of that too.  I think it will work by subscribing to the events you mentioned.  I was just hoping that there was a way to access what vscode already does since MS must be using those events to maintain their own list.

Comment: @user what go back does is cycle through locations you edited.  So if there are more than two of these it will visit them all.  What I want is just switching between the last used buffer and the current one.  And when you do the switch, the current buffer becomes the last buffer so only two editors are involved.  Ctrl+Tab does this if you press and release.  But the little selection window pops up briefly.  I just want to switch buffers.

Comment: See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/136878 what you wanted but not enough interest.

Comment: So based on what @Mark said, this approach is the only answer for now. If I write the code or find it I will post it here.